# Can we create an HttpResponse Object using the "new" keyword in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-ws

I'm working on chapter 4 of Martin Kalin's ["Web Services Up and running"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521134.do) book.

In the RestfulTeams exercise there is a method to returns a simple `HttpResponse` for a restful WS, like:

```
private Source response_to_client(String msg) {
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    response.setResponse(msg);
    ByteArrayInputStream stream = encode_to_stream(response);
    return new StreamSource(stream);
}
```

But I didn't find any library in Java where I can get the `HttpResponse` class (although I don't think we can create this object directly as in the above method).

Any clarifications will be helpful on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are thinking about the [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html). You can't create your own response objects out of it; the server creates instances of it and makes them available to your application.

But the class in the example is called `HttpResponse` which either is an error or some other class that the book omits to present.

Writing books is hard, so mistakes can slip by. That's why, after the book is printed, the mistakes that are discovered are [documented in an errata](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596521134). You usually find explanations there and there is always [the source code for the book](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596521134/) available for study.

Download the source code and I think you'll find what you are looking for, mainly this:

```
package ch04.team;

import java.io.Serializable;

// Serialized for responses on successful POSTs and PUTs
public class HttpResponse implements Serializable {
    private String resp;
    public void setResponse(String resp) { this.resp = resp; }
    public String getResponse() { return this.resp; }
}
```